# Is there a way to use a constant as a field of django ninja schema?

Tags: python, django-ninja

I have a class that has a constant:

```
class ClassA:
  CONSTANT = 'const_value'
```

I would like to have a django ninja schema that has the value of const as a field like:

```
class MySchema1(ninja.schema):
  const_value: str
```

but without repeating the value
This doesn't work:

```
class MySchema2(ninja.schema):
  ClassA.CONSTANT: str
```